# Var is not defined but why?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have a little problem with Codemirror (http://codemirror.net/manual.html)

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function ust()
    {    
        pa_textareas();
    });
    
    function pa_textareas()
    {
            var textarea = document.getElementById('ta_1');
          var editor_1 = new MirrorFrame(CodeMirror.replace(textarea), {
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",                
            parserfile: ["tokenizejavascript.js", "parsejavascript.js"],
            stylesheet: "js/js_parser/jscolors.css",
            path: "js/js_parser/",
            autoMatchParens: false,
            content: 'test kjskljsklj skjs lkj slkj sl',
            initCallback: function(getContents) { e1_ct  = ''+editor_1.mirror.getCode()+''; },
            onChange: function (n) { e1_ct = ''+editor_1.mirror.getCode()+''; }
          });
              
          var textarea = document.getElementById('ta_2');
          var editor_2 = new MirrorFrame(CodeMirror.replace(textarea), {
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",                
            parserfile: ["tokenizejavascript.js", "parsecss.js"],
            stylesheet: "js/js_parser/csscolors.css",
            path: "js/js_parser/",
            autoMatchParens: false,
            content: 'blub kasjdkljas dkjas lkdj alskj dlk',
            initCallback: function(getContents) { e2_ct  = ''+editor_2.mirror.getCode()+''; },
            onChange: function (n) { e2_ct = ''+editor_2.mirror.getCode()+''; }
          });
    
    }
```

I want to insert a button which formats the code, but I get always an error.

Button:

```
onclick="editor_2.mirror.reindent();"
```

Result:
-> "editor_2 is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of `editor_2` is the function `pa_textareas`. Since you are calling it using an intrinsic event handler attribute, you can't reach the variable.

You should probably be assigning the event handler with JavaScript inside the `pa_textareas` function.

Since you are using jQuery (At least I assume you are, there are other libraries with the stupid `$` variable):

```
jQuery('some selector').click(function () { editor_2.mirror.reindent(); });
```

Since the anonymous function is declared inside `pa_textareas` it will have access to variables defined in that scope.

Comment: I understand, logical. Thx for the fast help. Btw: Why is the $ stupid?

Comment: Because it is (a) Meaningless, (b) Used by different common libraries to mean different things, and (c) reserved (in the ECMAScript standard) for machine generated code.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no point in your code where you assign a value to editor_code_2, but you try to use it twice.

Comment: Not only that.  But he also needs to be sure where ever he defines the illusive "editor_code_2", is outside of his DOM ready closure.

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake in the example code. It is editor_2

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find anywhere in your code where you create a variable called `editor_code_2`. This is why you are getting the error. It seems you have mispelled your `editor_2` variable.

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake in the example code. It is editor_2.